# Execute an instruction later

Tags: c++

I would like to give an instruction as a parameter:

```
execute_at_frame(int frame_number, <instruction>)
{
    for(f = 1 ; f < F_MAX ; f++)
    {
        /* other instructions */
        if (f == frame_number)
            /* execute <instruction> */
        /* other instructions */
    }
}
```

- One type of call: `execute_at_frame(5,execute(42));`
- Another type of call: `execute_at_frame(6,process());`

Is that (or something similar) possible?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) (C++11):

```
template <class F>
void execute_at_frame(int frame_number, F instruction)
{
    for(int f = 1 ; f < F_MAX ; f++)
    {
        /* other instructions */
        if (f == frame_number)
            instruction();
        /* other instructions */
    }
}

/* ... */

execute_at_frame(5,process); // no bind for functions without parameters
execute_at_frame(5,std::bind(execute,42));
```

Otherwise you'll have to prepare a interface for instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Your `<instruction>` parameter can either be a function pointer (i.e. a pointer to an `execute` function); or, it can be a reference to an instance of a class, which has an `execute` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function pointer along with (if needed) some parameters. It could look like this:

```
typedef void (*Instruction)(int);

void foo(int)
{
    // do something
}

void execute_at_frame(int frame_number, Instruction ins, int param)
{
    for(int f = 1 ; f < F_MAX ; f++)
    {
        /* other instructions */
        if (f == frame_number)
            ins(param);
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
execute_at_frame(1000, foo, 42);
```

If you use variadic templates, you can make it work with any signature. Simplified example:

```
void foo(int)
{
}

float bar(int, char, double)
{
    return 1.0;
}

template<typename F, typename... Args>
void execute(F ins, Args... params)
{
    ins(params...);
}

int main()
{
    execute(foo, 1);
    execute(bar, 1, 'a', 42.0);
}
```

You'll need C++11 compiler for that.

Comment: Yes but the number (and type) of the parameters `param` may change a lot... it is not always an `int` and it is not always one argument :-/

Answer (score 0):

your  parameter also can be a base class pointer,point to Derived class which has  a virtual function

Answer (score 0):

Code for using a function as a parameter:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int instruction(int instruc)
{
     return instruc ;
}


template<typename F>
void execute_at_frame(int frame, const F& function_instruction)
{
     std::cout << function_instruction(frame) << '\n';
}


int main()
{
     execute_at_frame(20, instruction);  //  use reference
     execute_at_frame(40, &instruction); //  use pointer




  cout<<" \nPress any key to continue\n";
  cin.ignore();
  cin.get();

   return 0;
}
```